# Como buscar valor en un arreglo sin ciclo for

Tags: c++, array, while

no tengo mucha experiencia en c++ y tengo la siguiente duda: Tengo un arreglo/vector de N elementos, y tengo que ingresarlo a una condición while para comprobar si alguno de sus elementos es igual a un numero constante k, pero la idea es que cada vez que vuelva al while, el arreglo busque el numero k en todos los elementos repetidamente (osea desde 0 hasta N-1 todas las veces que pase por el while). En resumen, quiero que el while siempre pregunte si el numero k esta en todo el arreglo .He ahí el porque no puedo usar ciclo for (o eso pienso). Por supuesto que al arreglo se le cambiarán los valores dentro del ciclo para que el while finalice alguna vez.
En definitiva lo que expongo es :

```
while(arreglo(i)==k){} //con i=0,N-1
```

Comment: No es claro lo que planteas. De todas formas un arreglo puede iterarse con ciclo For o While recorriendo todas las posiciones

Comment: ¿Quieres comprobar si k es igual a algun elemento de la lista con el ciclo while?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que comparar cada valor de un array con un número ya sabrás hacerlo, por eso me limitaré a responder sobre cómo recorrer un array sin utilizar un for. Utilizando while la cosa cambia un poco, pero sigue siendo sencillo:

```
int i = 0; //Declara una variable que se encargará de ser la que cuente, como si fuera un for.

while(i < longitud){

    //Bloque de código en el que comparas cada valor del array con un número.

    i++; //Para que el valor de la variable contador se actualice y puedas salir del bucle.
}
```

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda. Si tienes alguna duda, no te cortes en responder. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Usar **for** o **while** depende de tu necesidad:

For lo usarás siempre que quieras comprobar todos y cada uno de los elementos de cierto contenedor de datos.
While lo usarás siempre que quieras buscar algo,repetir, hacer X evento sin tener que recorrer todas as posiciones del contenedor en cuestión.

Volviendo a tu problema, yo entiendo que si quieres comprobar el número total de  veces que se repite X número en Y contenedor,para asegurarte de que has "contado" con todas las X (o valores iguales K en tu caso) y darle la mayor consistencia tendrías que pasar por todas las habitaciones. Si lo que te interesa es saber el número de K's que hay en ese vector, puedes ayudarte de un contador auxiliar.

Si lo piensas, tu **while** hará lo mismo que un **for** al tener que recorrer todo el vector.

**Así que como conclusión, decirte:**

1) Puedes usar tanto for como while (a menos que te lo estén obligando explícitamente en el enunciado).
2) Mi propuesta (si he entendido bien tu problema) seria:

```
const int K = 10;       //Ejemplo de valor para K

int cK = 0;             //counterK => Contador de K
int V[X] = {};          //Vector V con tamaño X

for(int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
    if(X[i] == K)
    {
        cK++;
    }
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

En general, se considera que un bucle `for` debe ser usado cuando se sabe la cantidad de vueltas que debe dar el bucle y los bucles `while` o `do`-`while` para cuando no se sabe.

Tu caso sería uno de los usables con bucle `for`, ya que sabes que quieres recorrer un conjunto cerrado de datos:

```
bool encontrado = false;
for (auto b = std::begin(arreglo), e = std::end(arreglo); !encontrado && b != e; ++b)
    encontrado = *b == k;
```

Por supuesto, la convención mencionada en el primer párrafo es una guía de uso, puedes usar los bucles `for`, `while` o `do`-`while` como quieras, pero usarlos de maneras contraintuitivas puede hacer que tu código sea difícil de entender, aquí tienes el mismo bucle anterior en formato `while`:

```
bool encontrado = false;
auto b = std::begin(arreglo), e = std::end(arreglo);
while (!encontrado && b != e)
    encontrado = *b == k;
```

#### Propuesta.

No reinventes la rueda, C++ ya dispone de utilidades para buscar valores en colecciones, como la función [`std::find` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
auto posicion_k = std::find(std::begin(arreglo), std::end(arreglo), k);
auto encontrado = posición_k != std::end(arreglo);
```